# qemu vnc on android emulator not responding to keyboard and mouse

Tags: android, qemu, vnc

I am trying to access Android emulator via VNC. Android apps such as droid-vnc server are not working. So, I used qemu vnc

```
emulator -avd VNCvd -qemu -vnc :4
    (running at port 5904)
```

The display is good on tightvnc viewer but I can't input anything such as touch and keyboard. I haven't got past the lock screen yet. I tried -usbdevice tablet argument with no luck. How do I make it completely work? Any help would be appreciated :)